# Five people are tossing a coin ten times. What is the probability that at least 1 person gets heads 10 times?

Tags: probability

I know that the probability that one person getting heads all ten times is

```
1/(2^10) or 1/1024.
```

I also know the calculation when using "at least one" is

```
P(At least one) = 1 - P(None).
```

The probability of one person getting no heads is the same:

```
1/1024.
```

The part that is confusing is the number of people.  Is it

```
P(At least one) = 1 - (1/1024)^5?
```

If there were 100 people tossing a coin, the probability that at least one person gets all ten heads is

```
P(At least one) = 1 - (1/1024)^100?
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What you calculated was the probability of at least one of your persons having *not* flipped all heads.  Compare the proposed formula to the case where it is one person.  $1-(1/1024)^\color{red}{1}$ doesn't agree with what you would have expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The probability of getting $10$ heads is $\frac1{2^{10}}$.

Let $X$ be the number people getting $10$ heads, this follows binomial distribution $Bin(n, \frac1{2^{10}})$.

Hence $$P(X \ge 1) = 1-P(X=0)=1-\left( 1-\frac1{2^{10}}\right)^{n}$$

Answer (score 3):

The probability that at least one person gets heads ten times, equals 1 minus the probability that no one gets heads ten times. As you correctly derived, the probability of getting heads for a specific individual equals $\frac{1}{2^{10}}$. Then, the probability we are looking for equals:

$$1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{2^{10}}\right)^5 \approx 0.0049$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have $n$ people, each of whom tosses a coin $m$ times and that coin falls heads with probability $p$. Then the probability that the exact person chosen by us gets all heads is $p^m$. Thus the probability that he does not is $1- p^m$. So the probability that none of them had all heads is $(1 - p^m)^n$. And thus the probability, that at least one of them had all heads is $1 - (1 - p^m)^n$. That is the answer.